# Error in component $injector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am loading my views in my `app.js`:

```
// create the module and name it testApp
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
testApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'js/ng-app/views/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    });

    .when('/search', {
        templateUrl : 'js/ng-app/views/search.html',
        controller  : 'searchController'
    });

});
```

My search partial looks like that:

My `searchController.js`:

```
testApp.controller("searchController", function($scope, $http){

    $scope.apiKey = "97f25560b91ea3ad6c84e6f8c7677e4d";
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.filterText = null;
    $scope.init = function() {
        //API requires a start date
        var today = new Date();
        //Create the date string and ensure leading zeros if required
        var apiDate = today.getFullYear() + ("0" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "" + ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
        $http.jsonp('http://api.trakt.tv/calendar/premieres.json/' + $scope.apiKey + '/' + apiDate + '/' + 30 + '/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
            //As we are getting our data from an external source, we need to format the data so we can use it to our desired affect
            //For each day get all the episodes
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, index){
                //The API stores the full date separately from each episode. Save it so we can use it later
                var date = value.date;
                //For each episodes add it to the results array
                angular.forEach(value.episodes, function(tvshow, index){
                    //Create a date string from the timestamp so we can filter on it based on user text input
                    tvshow.date = date; //Attach the full date to each episode
                    $scope.results.push(tvshow);
                });
            });
        }).error(function(error) {

        });
    };
});
```

However I get:

```
Module Error
error in component $injector
Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/nomod?p0=digi...
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:6:449
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:20:260
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:21:262
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:29:175
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:7:274)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:29:115)
    at $b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:32:232)
    at Zb.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:17:431
```

I think that is because I use `ngRoute`. However how to fix this issue without removing `ngRoute`?

I appreciate your replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngRoute` module (or angular route) is not bundled with `angular.js` anymore and needs to be included separately. Have you remembered to do so?

From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route):

> $route is used for deep-linking URLs to controllers and views (HTML
>   partials). It watches $location.url() and tries to map the path to an
>   existing route definition.
>
> **Requires the ngRoute module to be installed.**

And [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) is the documentation page with information on how to obtain `angular-route.js`.

`ngRoute` was moved to its own module from version 1.2.0 of angular. From the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> due to 5599b55b, applications that use $route will now need to load an
>   angular-route.js file and define a dependency on the ngRoute module.